# Torrent tracker proxy

Tags: python, proxy, flask, openshift, bittorrent

I'm trying to implement a scipt on OpenShift, which works to bypass a very basic firewall in my college.

The aim is that I add the OpenShift address to the tracker list in any torrent I am running.

The client requests the script for peers.

The script accepts the peer list request and then asks for the list itself from a valid tracker. For testing purposes I have hardcoded this into the script as the tracker works for the test torrent without the firewall.

The response is passed back to the torrent client on my computer.

```
MyPC <==> Openshift <==> Tracker
```

This code is not working for some reason. I followed the flask [quick start guide](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/) and the OpenShift getting [started guide](https://www.openshift.com/promotions/ebook/thanks) .

I am new to networking so please help me out.

This is the routes.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os,urllib2
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app=Flask(__name__)
app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS']=True

@app.route('/announce/')
def  tormirror_test():
    q=request.query_string
    u=urllib2.urlopen("http://exodus.desync.com:6969/announce?"+str(q))
    return u

@app.route("/<name>")
def insulter(name):
    return "this is a test code====="+name

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: I think part of it is that your university may be blocking the connection back to your computer from OpenShift. My guess is your university blocks incoming connections on port 6969

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think part of it is that your university may be blocking the connection back to your computer from OpenShift. My guess is your university blocks incoming connections on port 6969

Just putting it here so you can mark it answered